# What shall I change in my code to get this XML format after serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, format

This is my class: [Language.cs](http://pastebin.com/xtscJbsN) (Full commented, that's why I posted it as a link)
The targetted code I need to change:

```
[Serializable]
public struct Text
{
    private string _Key;
    private string _Value;

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Key
    {
        get { return _Key; }
        set { _Key = value; }
    }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _Value; }
        set { _Value = value; }
    }

    public Text(string key, string value)
    {
        _Key = key;
        _Value = value;
    }
}
```

Currently, when I use the Save() method, I get a XML file like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>LangName</Name>
  <Texts>
    <Text Key="Welcome" Value="Welcome {0}!" />
    <Text Key="YourAge" Value="Your age is {0} !" />
  </Texts>
</Language>
```

And I'm looking for getting a file like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Language xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>LangName<Name/>
  <Texts>
    <Text Key="Welcome">Welcome {0}!<Text/>
    <Text Key="YourAge">Your age is {0} !<Text/>
  </Texts>
</Language>
```

Do you have an idea of what shall I change in my code to get this XML format after saving it ?

Thanks a lot :D

Comment: StackOverflow questions are intended to have long-lasting archival & reference value, so code (relevant snippets) must be included. Please include at least key sections into your question.

Comment: Sorry, It's my first question in this wonderful developer community website :) Question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into customizing/ configuring the `XmlSerializer` before you serialize. You will most likely need to set XmlAttributeOverrides, to set the desired attribute(s) as XmlText.

Specifically:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfaxz1a0.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmltext.aspx

Comment: Thanks ! Didn't see XmlText ;)